# How to run Pivot in Openquery in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i am trying to pull  Top 3 account Id for every sales person which they are dealing in columns wise and trying to run below query but getting error " Incorrect syntax near '1' "

Can someone please suggest why that error is

SQL Code :

```
    Select   *   
        from openquery([server01],'select  distinct Seller_id, Account_id, Account_Name, 
                                    Account_rank from
                           (Select distinct Seller_ID, Account_id,Account_Name,Revenue,                                                                          
                            dense_rank () over( partition by Seller_ID  order by 
                            Revenue desc ) as Account_Rank 
                            from Table_Account ) a
                   PIVOT (
                         Max (Account_id) FOR Account_Rank in( ''1'' ,''2'',''3'' ) 
                        )AS pvt                                                                          
                   where account_rank <=3  and                           
                   order by Seller_ID ')
```

Comment: `Account_Rank` is integer, use `in ( [1], [2], [3] )`. Also you have a extra `and` just before `order by`. Test your query on the target server first, make sure it is working before you use it in `OPENQUERY()`. It is much easier to debug this way

Comment: @Squirrel Thank you so much that resolved the error .  it working now after  adding [ ]

Answer (score 0):

I tried below query as per the above comment and it worked

SQL Code :

Select * from openquery([server01],'select  distinct Seller_id,
Account_id, Account_Name, Account_rank from (Select distinct
Seller_ID, Account_id,Account_Name,Revenue,
dense_rank () over( partition by Seller_ID  order by Revenue desc )
as
Account_Rank from Table_Account ) a
PIVOT (
Max (Account_id) FOR
Account_Rank in( '[1]' ,'[2]','[3]' )
)AS pvt
where account_rank <=3 order by Seller_ID ')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).